# DB Link from oracle -> ms sql ORA-28545 & ORA-02063

Tags: sql-server, oracle

We have Oracle 12c – installed on Windows Server 2016 and MS SQL Server 2017 – installed on Windows Server 2019.

When we try to use DB link from Oracle -> MS SQL via **SELECT count(*) FROM SMSOUT@TOSIMSQLSERVER** we obtain the following error:

```
ORA-28545: error diagnosed by Net8 when connecting to an agent
Unable to retrieve text of NETWORK/NCR message 65535
ORA-02063: preceding 2 lines from TOSIMSQLSERVER
28545. 0000 -  "error diagnosed by Net8 when connecting to an agent"
*Cause:    An attempt to call an external procedure or to issue SQL
           to a non-Oracle system on a Heterogeneous Services database link
           failed at connection initialization.  The error diagnosed
           by Net8 NCR software is reported separately.
*Action:   Refer to the Net8 NCRO error message.  If this isn't clear,
           check connection administrative setup in tnsnames.ora
           and listener.ora for the service associated with the
           Heterogeneous Services database link being used, or with
           'extproc_connection_data' for an external procedure call.
Error at Line: 1 Column: 29
```

The DB Link is created by **CREATE DATABASE LINK TOSIMSQLSERVER CONNECT TO "oms" IDENTIFIED BY "…our_pwd…" USING 'simsqlserver';**

**\hs\admin\initsimsqlserver.ora:**

```
# This is a sample agent init file that contains the HS parameters that are
# needed for the Database Gateway for ODBC
#
# HS init parameters
#
HS_FDS_CONNECT_INFO = simsqlserver
HS_FDS_TRACE_LEVEL = OFF
```

**\network\admin\listener.ora:**

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\oracle\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\oracle\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\oracle\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr12.dll")
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = simsqlserver)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\oracle\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = dg4odbc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = oracle12.pds.opds.cz)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

**\network\admin\tnsnames.ora:**

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\oracle\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORACLE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = oracle12.pds.opds.cz)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = oracle.pds.opds.cz)
    )
  )

LISTENER_ORACLE =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = oracle12.pds.opds.cz)(PORT = 1521))

simsqlserver = 
(DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=oracle12.pds.opds.cz)(PORT=1521)) 
    (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=simsqlserver)) 
    (HS=OK)
)
```

**\network\admin\sqlnet.ora:**

```
# sqlnet.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\oracle\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

# This file is actually generated by netca. But if customers choose to 
# install "Software Only", this file wont exist and without the native 
# authentication, they will not be able to connect to the database on NT.

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
```

Can somebody help me find where is the problem ? The SQL ODBC data source test is OK. Also TNSPING to simsqlserver is OK.

**EDIT 11.03.2020:**
Our Oracle is:

```
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
"CORE   12.2.0.1.0            Production"
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
```

After setting HS_FDS_TRACE_LEVEL = 16 and after lsnrctl stop + lsnrctl start we have the following logs:

**\oracle\diag\rdbms\oracle\oracle\trace\alert_oracle.log:**

```
2020-03-11T13:27:40.813789+01:00
HS:  Unable to establish RPC connection to HS Agent...
HS:  ... Agent SID = (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=oracle12.pds.opds.cz)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=simsqlserver))), NCR error = 65535 Unable to retrieve text of NETWORK/NCR message 65535

HS:  Unable to establish RPC connection to HS Agent...
HS:  ... Agent SID = (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=oracle12.pds.opds.cz)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=simsqlserver))), NCR error = 65535 Unable to retrieve text of NETWORK/NCR message 65535
```

**\oracle\diag\rdbms\oracle\oracle\alert\log.xml:**

```
<msg time='2020-03-11T13:27:40.938+01:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='rdbms'
type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ORACLE12'
host_addr='::1' module='SQL Developer' pid='2952'>
<txt>HS:  Unable to establish RPC connection to HS Agent...
</txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2020-03-11T13:27:40.938+01:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='rdbms'
type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ORACLE12'
host_addr='::1' module='SQL Developer' pid='2952'>
<txt>HS:  ... Agent SID = (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=oracle12.pds.opds.cz)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=simsqlserver))), NCR error = 65535 Unable to retrieve text of NETWORK/NCR message 65535
</txt>
</msg>
```

Comment: You might get better help from dbas.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Dave Costa dbas.stackexchange.com - The Q&A site dbas.stackexchange.com doesn't seem to exist…yet.

Comment: Sorry, it's just dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: set `HS_FDS_TRACE_LEVEL = 16` for diagnostic error. Are you using oracle 64 bit or 32? I used oracle 12.2.0.1 64 bit and odbc 64 bit for tests. It is OK!

Comment: @DmitryDemin still not work, added logs from trace level 16

Comment: @kulatamicuda add the trace files in the $ORACLE_HOME\hs\trace directory.

Comment: @kulatamicuda You need to configure the system DSN ODBC 64 bit, not system  DSN ODBC 32 bit.

Comment: @DmitryDemin ODBC is 64Bit. In ORACLE_HOME\hs\trace there are no files.

Comment: @kulatamicuda in file initsimsqlserver.ora  change HS_FDS_TRACE_LEVEL = OFF to HS_FDS_TRACE_LEVEL = 16

Comment: for host on tnsnames, try using LOCALHOST instead of ip address: ` (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = LOCALHOST)(PORT = 1521))`

Comment: Some of the files you show _should_ be from the oracle server, some from the gateway server ... which are not _necessarily_ the same.  And we have no way of knowing if you've shown the correct ones or not.  Debugging a gateway issues is simple and complex at the same time.  Simple because it is a straight line of config pointing to the next.  Complex because there are a lot of them.  I've put together a complete description at  https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2018/09/19/the-oracle-transparent-gateway/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)
```

line from sqlnet.ora. That isn't part of the specified configuration for DG4ODBC, per [MOS Doc ID 1266571.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=196819339363906&id=1266572.1&displayIndex=1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=l5m7mk6v4_128).

Comment: It's really intended to be a server-side setting, but it often gets set  by default for clients too. I have had to remove it a lot over the years. :-)